# DKIM not verified but dns record match key

Tags: phpmailer, dkim

Strugglign to get DKIM working. currently this is mail-tster result.

https://www.mail-tester.com/test-38w40jo78

im mainly missing the DKIM here is my dns records.

```
 truebud.ca text = "truebud-64839v5873958h3ddrg._domainkey.truebud.ca k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQChKyCHHZEkrYfTdcB2VX0nKL8Vhicb+xQsNswOgo5+IK2ipg97VJb+lKAT+jHMXyk4KPTkUUI/8rwa2IfUKsr/BQXy6csNkmM0Y00H5/+QRAYn+ktoRWO1zXvO2sygzCELgGxcj5pHkOd4xLGhTnTpHh7UAjTp" "/swV5E18dpAubQIDAQAB"
 truebud.ca text = "v=DMARC1\; p=none"
 truebud.ca text = "v=spf1 a mx ip4:216.221.70.222 ~all"
 truebud.ca text = "_domainkey.truebud.ca o=~\; r=info@truebud.ca"
```

and here is my code for phpmailer

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
//use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$site = 'truebud.ca';
$sitename = 'Truebud';
try {
    //Server settings
    //$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = '216.221.70.222';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'info@'.$site;                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '[pass]';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@'.$site,$sitename);
    $mail->addAddress('test-38w40jo78@srv1.mail-tester.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@'.$site,$sitename);
    $mail->addCC('cc@'.$site);
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@'.$site);

    // Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Truebud promotion';
    $mail->Body    = 'wall o' text';
    $mail->AltBody = 'wall 'o text';
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@".$site."?subject=Unsubscribe>,<http://".$site."/unsubscribe.php>");
    $mail->DKIM_domain = $site;
    $mail->DKIM_private = "rsa.private"; //path to file on the disk.
    $mail->DKIM_selector = $sitename."-64839v5873958h3ddrg";// change this to whatever you set during step 2
    $mail->DKIM_passphrase = "";
    $mail->DKIM_identity = $mail->From;

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Ive been at this for a week. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their error says:

> We were not able to retrieve your public key.
>   Please ensure that you inserted your DKIM TXT DNS record on your domain truebud.ca using the selector Truebud-64839v5873958h3ddrg.

I can see what's wrong — your DKIM DNS entry is incorrectly formatted.

```
# dig txt Truebud-64839v5873958h3ddrg._domainkey.truebud.ca
Truebud-64839v5873958h3ddrg._domainkey.truebud.ca. 120 IN TXT "truebud-64839v5873958h3ddrg._domainkey.truebud.ca v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQChKyCHHZEkrYfTdcB2VX0nKL8Vhicb+xQsNswOgo5+IK2ipg97VJb+lKAT+jHMXyk4KPTkUUI/8rwa2IfUKsr/BQXy6csNkmM0Y00H5/+QRAYn+ktoRWO1zXvO2sygzCELgGxcj5pHkOd4xLGhTnT" "pHh7UAjTp/swV5E18dpAubQIDAQAB"
```

You've got the hostname inside the record value - it should start with `v=DKIM1`, like:

```
truebud.ca text = "v=DKIM1; k=rsa\; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQChKyCHHZEkrYfTdcB2VX0nKL8Vhicb+xQsNswOgo5+IK2ipg97VJb+lKAT+jHMXyk4KPTkUUI/8rwa2IfUKsr/BQXy6csNkmM0Y00H5/+QRAYn+ktoRWO1zXvO2sygzCELgGxcj5pHkOd4xLGhTnTpHh7UAjTp" "/swV5E18dpAubQIDAQAB"
```

However, while I was testing that I saw you had changed it, so I guess you spotted the same mistake!

Comment: yes i have. i was able to resolve my DKIM. i tried 2048 bit key but the DNS wasnt accepting it. what is the correct way to do this? Also an update on mail-tester.com/test-m2rcvr19s. I am unsure what the DMARC syntax would be and im a tad confused on resolving th rDNS issu also. how do yuo go about that?

Comment: Glad that worked. Big keys are usually split into quoted sections, which I see you're already doing, but some DNS providers just don't let you use values that big in DNS, even though it's completely valid. There are plenty of guides for how to set up DMARC and what it all means - it's too big a question for SO. Reverse DNS is usually set up through your hosting provider's admin interface because it needs to be configured in their DNS rather than yours.

Comment: so reverse DNS i have no control over other than my ISP?